# jquery validate plugin validate single form depending on submit input clicked

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate, submit-button

I have a single form and 3 input type submit buttons: back, send, search. The "back" should not validate the form and take me back, the "send" should validate only the email field, the "search" should validate first name, last name and postcode. I have been working on this but to me the update/assign rules part seems a bit verbose. Maybe there's a way to do it better. I have a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1u7tb48L/
And this is my javascript:

```
$("#formValConfirmIdEmail").validate({
        debug: true,
        rules: {
            emailLogin: {
                required: true
            },
            firstName: {
                required: true
            },
            lastName: {
                required: true
            },
            postCode: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            emailLogin: {
                required: 'Required'
            },
            firstName: {
                required: 'Required'
            },
            lastName: {
                required: 'Required'
            },
            postCode: {
                required: 'Required'
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    });
// Update rules for send button
$('#formValConfirmIdEmail #sendBtn').on('click', function () {
    $('#emailLogin').rules('add', {
        required: true
    });
    $('#firstName').rules('remove');
    $('#lastName').rules('remove');
    $('#postCode').rules('remove');
    $('#firstName, #lastName, #postCode').closest('.control-group').removeClass('error');
    $('#formValConfirmIdEmail').valid();
});

// Update rules for search button
$('#formValConfirmIdEmail #searchBtn').on('click', function () {
    $('#firstName').rules('add', {
        required: true
    });
    $('#lastName').rules('add', {
        required: true
    });
    $('#postCode').rules('add', {
        required: true
    });
    $('#emailLogin').rules('remove');
    $('#emailLogin').closest('.control-group').removeClass('error');
    $('#formValConfirmIdEmail').valid();
});
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You've described your requirements but you have not explained the problem.  If you're just asking about an alternative way to do this, then not really.  There is no other way to toggle validation than to `add` and `remove` rules using the `rules()` method.

Comment: You could use a jQuery `.each()` and combine the selectors a bit:  http://jsfiddle.net/1u7tb48L/2/

Comment: Yes, I was thinking on using each(). I tried using an array where I store all elements and then use each(),but it only works on the first element of the array. Strangeee

Comment: Not strange; it's somewhat documented.  When using any of this plugin's methods, only the first matched element is considered.  So the workaround is to use an `.each()`.  Examine [my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1u7tb48L/2/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use the `.rules()` methods and when the selector contains multiple elements, wrap it inside of a jQuery `.each()`.

   ```
   $('#formValConfirmIdEmail #sendBtn').on('click', function () {
       $('#emailLogin').rules('add', 'required');
       $('#firstName, #lastName, #postCode').each(function () {
           $(this).rules('remove');
       });
       $('#firstName, #lastName, #postCode').closest('.control-group').removeClass('error');
       $('#formValConfirmIdEmail').valid();
   });
   ```

   **DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/1u7tb48L/4/**
2. Since it's just a simply boolean rule, declare it using `class="required"` and add/remove the `class` instead of using the `.rules()` method.

   ```
   $('#formValConfirmIdEmail #sendBtn').on('click', function () {
       $('#emailLogin').addClass('required');
       $('#firstName, #lastName, #postCode').removeClass('required').closest('.control-group').removeClass('error');
       $('#formValConfirmIdEmail').valid();
   });
   ```

   **DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/1u7tb48L/7/**

**NOTE**:  Your `errorPlacement` function is a bit superfluous as `error.insertAfter(element)` is already the default.  [Remove it entirely and the behavior is exactly the same](http://jsfiddle.net/1u7tb48L/8/).